# Display a tag before the custom Wordpress menu list content

Tags: wordpress, menu

Is that possible to insert a text before the menu items? In this case, I want to lead a `<h3>` tag for the list content (like a menu title). I tried the `if/else` to recognize that the menu have content and show the title. But if the menu have no content, so it should not have to display the title.

Here it is:

```
<ul>
$args = array(
  'menu'        => 'Destination • South America',
  'echo'        => false,
  'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
);

if (empty($args)) {
  echo "<li></li>";
}else{
  echo "<h3>South America</h3>";
}
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $args ), '<li><a>');
</ul>
```

Because I have content, so It should output:

**South America**
Argentina
Brazil
Chile
Colombia
Equador
Uruguay
Venezuela

If I would not have any content, so it should not display the **South America**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend a menu title by utilizing the 'items_wrap' function which generates the wrapping elements around the wp_menu_nav:

```
$args = array(
    'items_wrap' => '<h3>South America</h3><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: I changed to `'<h3>South America</h3><li id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</li>'` because the code is already wrapped into an `<ul>` tag. However, the `<h3>` has been not outputted in the console and there is an empty extra `<li>` leading the list! The "South America" appears but not wrapped in the `<h3>`.